# Lightsail / Bitnami : Redirect all www. traffic to non www

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, amazon-lightsail

I have tried many ways - but none seem to be working.

Am editing bitnami.conf under /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami

and adding the following the

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" ^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)" "%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://domain.com/$1" [L,R=302,NE]
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything ... also restarted apache.

Does anyone know how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure those rules get executed at all. Test it by implementing a definite syntax error in one of the rules, restart the apache server. You should immediately get an error (the server should fail to start). If not, then that file is not the configuration you are looking for.

About the actual rules you implemented ... I do not see an immedate issue with them, though they are somewhat exotic. I would suggest that instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI] [L,R=302]
```

And looking at that example I just realize that you issue might be that you forgot to enable the rewriting engine using `RewriteEngine on` ...